# How to perform client side data fetching in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, location, client, next.js

I am working on a search engine product and need to know the client country code.

I tried to get it with [this URL](https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json) and it returns server side country code.

How can I get the correct user country code when using `getInitialProps`?

Comment: Tried calling that API from the app when a component mounts?

Comment: Thanks, Drew for contact me.
I tried it on the server site from getInitialProps function.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';
// Vercel has created a data-fetching library called SWR (client side).
import useSWR from 'swr';

const API_URL = 'https://extreme-ip-lookup.com/json/';

async function fetcher(url) {
  const res = await fetch(url);
  const json = await res.json();
  return json;
}

function Index() {
  const { data, error } = useSWR(API_URL, fetcher);

  if (error) return <div>failed to load</div>;
  if (!data) return <div>loading...</div>;

  const { countryCode } = data;

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Country Code: {countryCode}</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Index;
```

Comment: I tried it already, but I am getting the server country code and not the client country code.

Comment: Think about this!
When you deploy on some server, it will return the deployed server country code and not the client country.

Comment: When the page is loaded in the browser SWR will fetch the data.

Comment: Ah, I am sorry.
I was missing the edition of your answer.
Let me check it again.

Comment: Worth noting that NextJS implicitly imports React in jsx files and [polyfills fetch](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/supported-browsers-features) on server & client so no need to import them, at least in recent versions.